# Constraints for message bubble

Tags: ios, swift

I am building a messaging app, so i am using message bubbles for conversation screen. But I have a problem. My screen looks like this:

[image]

You can see if message is long then it is breaking. I think my constrains is wrong.

**My code:**

```
    bubbleImageView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    messageLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: bubbleImageView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 10))
    contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: bubbleImageView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 4.5))
    bubbleImageView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: bubbleImageView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: messageLabel, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 30))
    contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: bubbleImageView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -4.5))

    bubbleImageView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: messageLabel, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: bubbleImageView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 3))
    bubbleImageView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: messageLabel, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: bubbleImageView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: -0.5))
    messageLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 218
    bubbleImageView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: messageLabel, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: bubbleImageView, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: -15))
```

**How can I resolve this problem ?**

Comment: First you may want to check out JSQMessagesViewController.  I think your problem could be with the table cell size. Try a higher estimatedRowHeight since I'm guessing you are using automatic cell sizing introduced in iOS 8. To test out this theory add subview clipping to the table cell or turn the tableViews cell divider lines back on.

Comment: Are you using a tableview for this?

Comment: Yes I am using tableview

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your view hierarchy is as

```
contentView -> bubbleImageView -> messageLabel
```

and you are using auto resizing cells.

Pin all the edges of bubbleImageView to contentView.

```
contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: bubbleImageView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

Same way do it for .Right, Top and .Bottom.

Similarly pin all the edges of messageLabel to bubbleImageView with appropriate constants.

```
contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: messageLabel, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: bubbleImageView, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 5))
```

Same way do it for .Right, Top and .Bottom.
No need to center messageLable in bubbleImageView.

Comment: Could you explain more ?